# Accessing an Object in an Object

Tags: parse-platform

I have an object that saves like this
    taskTime{"date":"2012-11-19","freq":"taskOnce","time":"05:22"}
Is there a way to access these inner objects?
I have tried this
    result.attributes.taskTime.freq
With no luck any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

result.get("taskTime").freq

That's just a guess, though. There's not enough info. Chrome's developer tools are your friends.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it just be:

```
taskTime.freq
```